# using Tweet button - link doesn't appear in tweet text at all

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter, tweets

My working code here correctly put the Tweet button on the page and allows the user to preview the tweet then commit it:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" 
    data-text="Check out this URL! "
    data-url="www.OurSite.com/UX1ab7"
    data-via="OurSite" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
    if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id; 
        js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
    }
    (document,"script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

If you recall (have a look at your own Tweets for example) you can paste into your tweet a functioning link - a link that one of your Twitter followers, upon reading your tweet, will notice

```
   'hey, I see an embedded URL here in this tweet -- I can tell it's a link 
    because it looks like a URL and its text color is a different color from 
    the other text in the tweet.  Here let me click on that url in the tweet
    and -- HEY it works, that blue-colored text IS a link, I just jumped to www.xyx.com.'
```

I was under the impression that in my code above the 'data-url' setting was supposed to make a visible, specially-colored link url appear right in the body of the tweet. Well it doesn't in my case.

In my code above, data-url="www.OurSite.com/UX1ab7"  is not even visible in the Tweet at all.
And changing the 'data-text' to

```
   data-text="Check out this URL! www.OurSite.com/UX1ab7"
```

The tweet generated by the code above is:   **Check out this URL! www.OurSite.com/UX1ab7**

but even though the 'www.OurSite.com/UX1ab7' URL appears within the tweet -- it's not a link, just text, and
has the same text color as the rest of the tweet.

The www.OurSite.com/UX1ab7 text in the tweet above does not

- look like a click-able link
- act like a click-able link

It's just text.

How do I get the Tweet button to display a click-able URL link with the Tweet button?
I thought the 'data-url' would make the link visible and clickable but it does not.

Comment: Have you tried adding "http://" in front of the URL? Twitter might be validating the `data-url` attribute and discarding invalid input.

Comment: Two things come to mind: you should probably prefix the protocol (http) and also,separate the text and link, isn't there a data-url attribute?

Comment: All 3 of you are correct.  The reason why my attempts to get the data-url to work (ie. show a click-able link instead of text) failed was -- our PHP variable containing the URL did *not* have http://.  Modifying the code to incorporate the http:// now has the 'data-url' working correctly -- a click-able link with colored text now appears in the body of the Tweet -- I'm giving +1 to y'all thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're tweeting, is it from a specific page? i.e. a blog post or information article? If so, I believe you can leave the `data-url` option out and it should pull in the URL from the address bar.

This is the code that we use for tweets

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
```

Which will pull down the page title (which you can define with the `data-text` tag) and the URL of the page you are currently on, so will give you something like

```
{{Title of Page or Title defined by data-text}} 
{{http://oursite.com/url_of_page_i_am_on}}
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, we actually need to tweet a PHP variable containing a link so we can't use the default behavior -- thanks for taking some time to help here, I appreciate it!

Comment: Is something like this more appropriate? http://fabien.potencier.org/article/20/tweeting-from-php

Comment: A lot of folks out there prefer that to the new OAuth, twitter has got clear of xml and username/password API access, OAuth and json's the meal ticket, that code looks like old-style pre-OAuth Twitter API access.   The equivalent code we wrote for our 1st tweet attempt like your example but updated for OAuth works but we switched to the Tweet button above as it displays a 'share' popup box allowing the user to confirm/edit/commit/or back out of the tweet whereas the other programmatic way just tweets w/no chance for the user to edit/commit/back out of the Tweet - thx for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the link you're sharing is not accessible to the public.  It doesn't work with local/development domains.

Edit:

Correction.  It wasn't working for me because I was using a relative url ('/blog' rather than 'https://mysite.com/blog').